# Bootstrap Modal Popup background view

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal, master-detail

I am working on a ASP.NET Core CRUD applciation using modal popup i have a master detail models Stock and Article. i used this code to display the modal popup:
StockController:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Category> categories = _dbcontext.Category.ToList();
        ViewBag.ListCategories = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
       
        List<Stock> AllStocks = _dbcontext.Stock.ToList();
        return View(AllStocks);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.Articles.Add(new Article() { ArticleId = 1 });
        return View("_AddStockPartialView", stock);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Stock stock)
    {
        if (stock != null)
        {
            _dbcontext.Stock.Add(stock);
            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Stock>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Theme.cshtml";
}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Stock</h3>
                <div class="card-tools">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addStock" onclick="GetDetails()">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        Ajouter
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" id="display">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    .....
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function GetDetails() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/Stock/Create",
            success: function (res) {

                $("#display").html(res);
                $("#addStock").modal('show');


            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

_AddStockPartialView.cshtml:

```
    @model GestionStock.Models.Stock

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_AddStockPartialView";
}


<div class="modal fade " role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="addStock" aria-labelledby="addStockLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5>Stock</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                        <select asp-for="CategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ListCategories"></select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    .......    

                    <table class="table table-striped" id="articleTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>    
                                <th>Numero serie</th>
                                <th>Marque</th>
                                <th>etat</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Articles.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Articles[i].NumeroSerie, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Articles[i].Marque, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Articles[i].Etat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            }

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnLastIndex" value="0" />
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" @*onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()"*@>Annuler</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sauvegarder</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine and the modal popup is displaying with master detail models. But when i click te button to display the modal popup, the background view (Index.cshtml) is changed like the picture below and the CategoryId SelectList isn't populating:

[image]

Although this is the index view which is supposed to display in the background of the modal popup:

[image]

So why is Index view chaning when displaying the modal popup?

Comment: Please check `return View("_AddStockPartialView", stock);` Try to change into `return PartialView("_AddStockPartialView", stock);`

Comment: I tried it, it does not display the modal popup and the table in index view isn't displaying too.

Comment: Could you share the  code of your models?

Comment: And what's your _Theme.cshtml look like?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

1. In controller, make some change in  create action.

   ```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            List<Category> categories = _dbcontext.Category.ToList();
            ViewBag.ListCategories = new SelectList(categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
            Stock stock = new Stock();
            stock.Articles.Add(new Article() { ArticleId = 1 });
            return  PartialView("_AddStockPartialView", stock);
        }
   ```

2.In the Index view:

remove table (`<table>`) before `<div class="card-body" id="display">`

3.In the  _Theme.cshtml, check and make sure you already have below code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/GestionStock.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
     ...
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

4.result(I use my model data to show the table) :

[image]

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand the 2nd point

Comment: @user4374239 I think you use `<div class="card-body" id="display">` to show modal , right ?

Comment: Yes i use it to load the master detail from Create action and show the modal

Comment: @user4374239 You set your index table inside  `<div class="card-body" id="display">`,  then use `$("#display").html(res);` to show  the modal , when the modal removed, it show nothing. So I suggest you set your index table outside  `<div class="card-body" id="display">` to keep table.

Comment: when i put the index table outside the div it shows both the table and the div  under the table in the background of the modal.

Comment: @user4374239  Ok, my index may different from yours, so don't remove the table, keep yours. Has your problem been solved ?

Comment: The SelectList is now populated thnaks to you but the problem of the modal background still persists.

Comment: @user4374239 What's ` modal background  ` look like ? Could you share the screen shot and the code ?

Comment: It looks like the first screen i shared in my post

Comment: @user4374239 Do you use `return  PartialView("_AddStockPartialView", stock);` ?  Is something like my image  that you want?